# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64, it seems just randomly happened to some third party framework using cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

### What happened

1. I used `Cocoapods` to manage some third-party frameworks
2. I used some private spec repos
3. More than one private repos have dependency on same third-party pods
4. After a modification of dependency structure,I build my workspace, it shows these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_iCarousel in iCarousel.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIButton", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iCarousel.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIScrollView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iCarousel.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIScreen", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iCarousel.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UITapGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iCarousel.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iCarousel.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_iCarousel in iCarousel.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIBarButtonItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iCarousel.o
  "_UITrackingRunLoopMode", referenced from:
      -[iCarousel startAnimation] in iCarousel.o
  "_CGSizeZero", referenced from:
      -[iCarousel setUp] in iCarousel.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPanGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iCarousel.o
  "_UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction", referenced from:
      -[iCarousel setUp] in iCarousel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

### What I've done to try to solve this problem?(none of them works)

1. Deleted Xcode caches by `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
2. Deleted Cocoapods caches by `$ rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"   $rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"   $pod update`
3. Update the Xcode version to 12.0.1

Oh no, same errors!

### What I've done next...

I decided to go the hard way, so I add those things to my `Podfile`:

```
if target.name == "iCarousel"
  config.build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
  config.build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS'] << '-framework "UIKit"'
  config.build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS'] << '-framework "CoreGraphics"'
end
```

Then, `pod install`

Build my project...

**Good news! nothing to do with iCarousel! Bad news, same old errors happened to another pod: `PomeloPush`**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue", referenced from:
      -[PomeloReachability startNotifier] in PomeloReachability.o
      -[PomeloReachability stopNotifier] in PomeloReachability.o
  "_SCError", referenced from:
      -[PomeloReachability startNotifier] in PomeloReachability.o
  "_SCErrorString", referenced from:
      -[PomeloReachability startNotifier] in PomeloReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[PomeloReachability isReachable] in PomeloReachability.o
      -[PomeloReachability isReachableViaWWAN] in PomeloReachability.o
      -[PomeloReachability isReachableViaWiFi] in PomeloReachability.o
      -[PomeloReachability connectionRequired] in PomeloReachability.o
      -[PomeloReachability isConnectionOnDemand] in PomeloReachability.o
      -[PomeloReachability isInterventionRequired] in PomeloReachability.o
      -[PomeloReachability reachabilityFlags] in PomeloReachability.o
      ...
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[PomeloReachability startNotifier] in PomeloReachability.o
      -[PomeloReachability stopNotifier] in PomeloReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[PomeloReachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in PomeloReachability.o
  "_CFHostStartInfoResolution", referenced from:
      +[PomeloHostRequest nslookup:] in PomeloHostRequest.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PomeloClient.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[PomeloReachability reachabilityWithHostname:] in PomeloReachability.o
  "_CFHostCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[PomeloHostRequest nslookup:] in PomeloHostRequest.o
  "_CFHostGetAddressing", referenced from:
      +[PomeloHostRequest nslookup:] in PomeloHostRequest.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPasteboard", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Pomelo_OpenUDID.o
  "_UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification", referenced from:
      -[PomeloClient addNotification] in PomeloClient.o
  "_UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification", referenced from:
      -[PomeloClient addNotification] in PomeloClient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Then I added some similar code in Podfile
Then `pod install`, build
Oh, a similar error happened to another pod:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      __OBJC_$_CATEGORY_UIViewController_$_KeyboardAnimation in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
  "_UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      -[UIViewController(KeyboardAnimation) getDurationFromNotification:] in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
  "_UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      -[UIViewController(KeyboardAnimation) getAnimationCurveFromNotification:] in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
  "_UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      -[UIViewController(KeyboardAnimation) getKeyboardRectFromNotification:] in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
  "_UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification", referenced from:
      -[UIViewController(KeyboardAnimation) an_subscribeKeyboardFrameChangesWithAnimations:] in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
      -[UIViewController(KeyboardAnimation) an_unsubscribeKeyboardFrameChanges] in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
  "_UIKeyboardWillShowNotification", referenced from:
      -[UIViewController(KeyboardAnimation) an_subscribeKeyboardWithBeforeAnimations:animations:completion:] in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
      -[UIViewController(KeyboardAnimation) an_unsubscribeKeyboard] in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
  "_UIKeyboardWillHideNotification", referenced from:
      -[UIViewController(KeyboardAnimation) an_subscribeKeyboardWithBeforeAnimations:animations:completion:] in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
      -[UIViewController(KeyboardAnimation) an_unsubscribeKeyboard] in UIViewController+KeyboardAnimation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

for now, it had happened on `pop`, `AFNetworking`, `SDWebImage`, `iCarousel`, `MJRefresh`, and so on...

### Any suggestions could help would be greatly appreciated!! I've stuck on this for a week...

Answer (score 1):

By looking out your observation you can try out the following suggestion:

1. Check if your cocoapods are updated to latest version.
2. remove all pods using  pod deintegrate.
3. check the dependencies of pods and try to install one by one. pod install.
4. also check the support of libraries to your swift version.
5. if both libraries have same code or extension it will give you the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions! I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Also could be helpful to remove all pods first:

```
pod deintegrate
```

then

```
pod install
```